# Silverlight RenderTransforms available to children?

Tags: silverlight

I have setup a StackPanel with a set of controls. Each control is an instance of the same class. The control is also a stack panel and has another custom control in it.  So:

```
StackPanel:
     CustomControl1:
           StackPanel:
                  CustomControl2:
                         ListBox
     CustomControl1:
           StackPanel:
                  CustomControl2:
                         ListBox
     CustomControl1:
           StackPanel:
                  CustomControl2:
                         ListBox
```

The RenderTransform is applied at the top stack panel. As expected, all child controls scale accordingly. This is great until I get to this last Listbox control. In that case, I want the scale to either be ignored, or handled differently (likly in the inverse direction).

Is there any way to exclude a control from the transformation? Alternativly, can I evaluate the transformation from within the Listbox?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could apply exactly the inverse of the transformation, though it may take some time to get just right.

If doing this in code, you could use `VisualTreeHelper` to walk up the tree and read the right values.

Alternatively, might you do some kind of creative:

```
StackPanel:
 StackPanel: APPLY transformation HERE instead for the first 2
  CustomControl1:
        StackPanel:
               CustomControl2:
                      ListBox
  CustomControl1:
        StackPanel:
               CustomControl2:
                      ListBox
 CustomControl1:
       StackPanel:
              CustomControl2:
                     ListBox
```